# Google is ignoring my robots.txt

Tags: php, seo, robots.txt, google-search

Here is content of my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /upload/
Disallow: /admin/
```

As you can see, I explicitly disallowed all robots to index the folders `images`, `upload` and `admin`. The problem is that one of my clients sent request for removing the content from the images folder because .pdf document from the `images` folder appeared in the google search results. Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong here, and why google indexed my folders?

Thx!

Comment: This is not really related to programming, and would be better asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Even we apply robot.txt google will search the folder. We need to restrict the directory with password. And better to put index.html file in all directory to avoid listing the files.

Comment: Question [reposted on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/68958/17633).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [Google Webmaster Docs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq#h17)

> If I block Google from crawling a page using a robots.txt disallow
>   directive, will it disappear from search results?
>
> Blocking Google from crawling a page is likely to decrease that page's
>   ranking or cause it to drop out altogether over time. It may also
>   reduce the amount of detail provided to users in the text below the
>   search result. This is because without the page's content, the search
>   engine has much less information to work with.

--

> **However, robots.txt Disallow does not guarantee that a page will not
>   appear in results**: Google may still decide, based on external
>   information such as incoming links, that it is relevant. If you wish
>   to explicitly block a page from being indexed, you should instead use
>   the noindex robots meta tag or X-Robots-Tag HTTP header. In this case,
>   you should not disallow the page in robots.txt, because the page must
>   be crawled in order for the tag to be seen and obeyed.

Set X-Robots-Tag header with noindex for all files in the folders. Set this header from your webserver config for the folders. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=de

1. Set header from Apache Config for pdf files:

   `<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
      Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
    </Files>`
2. Disable directory index'ing / listing of this folder.
3. Add a empty index.html with a "noindex" robots meta tag.

   `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
   <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex" />`
4. Force the removal of the indexed pages by manually using webmaster tools.

---

Question in the comment: How to forbid all files in the folder?

```
// 1) Deny folder access completely
<Directory /var/www/denied_directory>
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>

// 2) inside the folder, place a .htaccess, denying access to all, except to index.html
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch index\.html>
        Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

// 3) allow directory, but disallow specifc environment match
BrowserMatch "GoogleBot" go_away_badbot
BrowserMatch ^BadRobot/0.9 go_away_badbot

<Directory /deny_access_for_badbot>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from env=go_away_badbot
</Directory>  

// 4) or redirect bots to main page, sending http status 301
BrowserMatch Googlebot badbot=1
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:badbot} =1
RewriteRule ^/$ /main/  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your comment is really helpful. Thx!

Comment: how to forbid all files, not just .pdfs?

Comment: I've added two examples to the answer. Basically it's denying directory access via Apache Config file. A good approach is to blacklist the folder (deny all) and then to add exceptions,  whitelisting the files (allow  from all), which you want to show.

Comment: The second problem is that these folders should be publicly accessible, but we just want to discourage search engines for indexing it.

Comment: ok, i've added a third example, which uses BrowserMatch and an "deny from env" check to test what browser requests the directory. If it is one of the BrowserMatches refereced by go_away_badbots, then access is denied. Think of "go_away_badbots" as a list and extend the BrowserMatches. You see the correct Browser names for the spiders/crawlers/bots in your webserver access log or in the list at **http://user-agents.org/**. Only problem are bots which do not respect robots.txt and don't tell their name or fake their name.. then you are out of luck.

Comment: You've added this line for pdf's 
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
   Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
 </Files>

but I would like to add header for all file types in those folders.

Comment: Extend the directory directive.. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: Yup, beer is very welcome :) Actually, Files or FilesMatches might work, too. there are many ways to solve this. you will find it out by using the Apache docu.