# Is there meta for Google's bot to ignore apple-app-site-association and assetlinks.json?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, head, googlebot

I watch my logs when someone hits any of my site's 404 pages and I've noticed I get several alerts for Google's bot in regards to:

```
/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
/apple-app-site-association
/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

After several searches and references I was able to learn more about what they are from:

- [Google bot hits on files 'apple-app-site-association' and 'assetlinks.json' showing up in Google Webmasters as pages with errors](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95953/google-bot-hits-on-files-apple-app-site-association-and-assetlinks-json-show)
- [why does google request apple-app-site-association from every domain on the server?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85674/why-does-google-request-apple-app-site-association-from-every-domain-on-the-serv)

but if that site never intends to have an app is there a way in the head to tell Google Bot this?  When I search for answers I've run across:

- [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)
- [Apple-app-site-association not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531655/apple-app-site-association-not-found)
- [apple-app-site-association —with examples](https://gist.github.com/mat/e35393e9dfd9d7fb0972)

From Google:

- [Creating a Statement List](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/create-statement)
- [Statement List Syntax](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/statements)

However, none of my searches indicates how to build a file to inform Google that the client doesn't intend to have an app associated with the site or a way in the head to tell Google.

So far the only solution I've been able to conclude was use conditional in PHP to ignore the request like:

```
$apple_app = home_url() . '/apple-app-site-association';
if ($request != $apple_app) :
  // use the force
end if;
```

Comment: I use robots.txt myself. Works well

Comment: Per memory I thought Google ignored robots.txt?

Comment: Haha. No. They obey it. They are industry leaders in search engine tact. I had your problem - those ugly 404s - gone now.

Comment: Ah it was in regards to indexing which is why I thought Google ignored it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764711/google-is-ignoring-my-robots-txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google-bot will obey the [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182072?hl=en) directives. Try adding these rules to your robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /apple-app-site-association
Disallow: /.well-known/

# These are additional paths Google is known to search (optional)
Disallow: /m/
Disallow: /mobile/
```

I had your exact problem with the seemingly strange 404 log entries. They've stopped now. I hope this helps.